# Angular AuthGuard - is it a right solution?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, jwt, authorization

I would like to create a route guard for protecting routes against unauthorized users.

I am using jsonwebtoken for authorization, and at the moment storing that in localStorage.

My idea is, when a user wants to access a protected admin route, authguard sends the token for validation to the nodeJS/Express server that after validation returns a true or 401 (whether the user is admin) to the client side.

auth service:

```
isLoggedIn(){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('x-auth-token',localStorage.getItem('token') || '');
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/check-auth', {}, { headers: headers }).toPromise();
}
```

authGuard service:

```
canActivate(){
    return this.sign.isLoggedIn().then(res => {return res;}).catch(ex => {return ex});
}
```

My purpose would be to avoid manually setting a token key in the localstorage by the user to see the guarded route, even if he would not be able to implement any XHR request.

Could you please verify if its a good or bad idea and come up with better solution on security side?
Many thanks!

Comment: I think this is a good practice with the exception of the 401 response. Technically, the client did not make an invalid request. A 401 response indicates that the *contents* of the HTTP GET was invalid. The server should yield 200 for success, and contain a flag in the body that client reads to see if the user is allowed. 401 errors are logged in the console and network panels of the browser as bad requests.

Comment: Actually, 400 indicates that the content of the http request is invalid. 401 is indeed for unauthorized requests.

Comment: Thank you, i will correct the 401 response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice would be to manage roles (or permissions) at the model level on the server-side. For example a User class could have a roles property, such as :

```
auth.service.ts
myUser.roles = ['ROLE_ADMIN']
```

This way, when your user logins, you can store the information in your auth.service.ts

```
// auth.service.ts
get isAdmin() {
    return this.user.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN')
}
```

Note that usually you want to store this information in you app state management, whether it be plain rxjs, ngrx, ngxs...

Finally you would add an AuthInterceptor which would redirect your user if your API returns a 401.

Comment: Permissions are defined in mongoose models, and are included in the jwt. If i understand well, it would be better to store in client side service at authentication the permission of the logged in user, right?

Comment: Yes. You don't have to do a request to the API each time you want to navigate a restricted area of your app. The secure part of your app will be on the server-side anyway and is made possible by the jwt.